# Enter hex value in console

Tags: c++, input, console

I have a C++ program that read from stdin with function gets();
I cannot modify the code.

I want to type in console a character to put its hex value in a variable.
for instance

```
char var1[20];
gets(var1);
// type in console : AAAA(character 0)(character x41)
// the result in var1 would be  "AAAA\0\x41"
```

The example in itself makes little sense but you should get what I am aiming for.
I know how to input most character using  ALT+(hex number) typed with numpad, but I have no idea how to input \x00

Comment: One possible work-around:  write a second (one-line) program that outputs the desired string to stdout, then run both programs like this:  "./writestring | ./readhexstring"

Comment: Well, `\0` is `NUL`. In unix, you can usually do that with `ctrl+@`, unless I'm mis-remembering

Comment: redirect the input from a file